# Retorno de variavel em javascript = undefined

Tags: javascript

Eis o código:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Enviar(){
    var tempo = document.getElementById('tempo');
    var veloc = document.getElementById('veloc');

    var distancia = parseInt(tempo) * parseInt(veloc);
    var litros = parseInt(distancia) / 12;

    alert("Tempo gasto de viagem:"+tempo.value+"\nVelocidade média:"+veloc.value+
          "\nDistância percorrida:"+distancia.value+"\nLitros gastos:"+litros.value);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Porém no resultado ele diz que as variaveis distancia e litros são "undefined", sendo que deveriam conter os resultados da multiplicação e divisão.

Comment: O elemento 'tempo' e 'veloc' provavelmente não contêm quaisquer valor pode postar o HTML tambem?

Comment: <form id="form13">
            Tempo gasto na viagem:<input type="text" id="tempo">horas<br>
            Velocidade Média:<input type="text" id="veloc">km/h<br>
            <input type="submit" onclick="Enviar();" value="Enviar">
        </form>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As variáveis `tempo` e `veloc` são elementos, e não valores. Portanto devia ser:

```
var distancia = parseInt(tempo.value) * parseInt(veloc.value);
```

Já `distancia` e `litros` são valores, e não elementos. Por isso não faz sentido tentar pegar o `value` deles. O `alert` deveria ser:

```
alert("Tempo gasto de viagem:"+tempo.value+"\nVelocidade média:"+veloc.value+
      "\nDistância percorrida:"+distancia+"\nLitros gastos:"+litros);
```